# Reduce page width for a single page in WordPress zerif-lite theme using CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I wish to reduce the `page width` for only a single page on my website without altering the `theme` that I am using `(zerif-lite)`. I wish to do so using `CSS` i.e by adding `CSS` to `styles.css`. I am facing problems because I wish to do it only for one page without disturbing anything else.

Also there is an option of selecting the page template in which I have chosen **Full Width Template**. Where are these templates defined and how can I edit them?

[wordpress-templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgzq0.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like  .page-id-11 #yourdiv or class  in styles.css in the template directory , you should also have themplate files in wp-content/themes/yourtheme      and find something like single-fullwith.php or similar...